# Write to a file by PHP

Tags: php

I have a `Fetch.exe` in my Windows Server, in a command prompt running `Fetch.exe` returns some text output in the console.

I want to wrap `Fetch.exe` in a `exec` of PhP, and generate `result.txt`:

```
exec("Fetch/Fetch.exe > C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test/result.txt");
```

The test shows that `result.txt` has been indeed generated, however, it is empty.

Then, I created a simple `try.bat` in the same folder:

[image]

Similarly, an empty `result.txt` is generated.

By contrast, `exec("echo 123 > C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test/result.txt")` works fine.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

**Update 1:** Here is the permission of the folder `Fetch`, a user has all the permissions:

[image]

Comment: Probably the output of `Fetch.exe` changes depending on the user that executes it, or the user that executes PHP doesn't have permission to execute it.

Comment: Please see my update... users have all the permissions...

Comment: Is your php script into testaddbbacom directory?

Comment: Yes, it's in `testaddbbacom` directly, and we do see an empty `result.txt` is generated by the php script.

Comment: try to include Fetch.exe full path:  exec("C:\\inetpu\\testaddbbacom\\Fetch\\Fetch.exe > C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test/result.txt")

Comment: Cool, that works... But why should we use "\\" rather than "\" or "/" in the path of `Fetch.exe`?

Comment: If your path string goes with double quotes you must escape backslashes, if you use single quotes not. you can rewrite the exec call: exec('C:\inetpu\testaddbbacom\Fetch\Fetch.exe > C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test/result.txt') or exec('C:/inetpu/testaddbbacom/Fetch/Fetch.exe > C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test/result.txt')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If your path string goes with double quotes you must escape backslashes, if you use single quotes not. you can rewrite the exec call: exec('C:\inetpu\testaddbbacom\Fetch\Fetch.exe > C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test/result.txt') or exec('C:/inetpu/testaddbbacom/Fetch/Fetch.exe > C:/inetpub/testaddbbacom/test/result.txt') – @jlgsoftware